# Best pattern to namespacing a property with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, namespaces

I'm in the process of namespacing a couple of scripts in my project and after searching for a while, I'm not sure if I follow the best practices to namespacing properties.

Here is a sample of what I do:

```
   var myNamespace = myNamespace || {};

   $.extend(true, myNamespace, {
      subNamespace: {

      }
   });

   $.extend(true, myNamespace.subNamespace, {
      data: {}
   });

   $(document).ready(function () {
      myNamespace.subNamespace.data = "Value as string";

      alert(myNamespace.subNamespace.data);
   });
```

As you can see, the property name in this case is 'data'.

Is this the good approach to implement properties in namespace with javascript, jquery?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are there any specific reason you use `jQuery.extend` to add depth? At first glance, you might as well define the namespace using an object singleton:

```
var myNamespace = {
    subNamespace: {
        data: "Value as string"
    }
};
```

Comment: I use the jQuery.extend because I want to be able to contruct the properties and functions of the subNamespace in different steps. With your solution, you will have to define all that subNamespace can be contain at the same place. With my solution, if I add some functions and properties at one place and other to the same namespace at another place, I will not overrides the subNamespace define in my previous steps. It's possible that I'm wrong?!

Comment: You don’t need `jQuery.extend` to do that: `var top = {}; top.sub = {}; top.sub.data = 'whatever';`

Answer (score 1):

[Addy Osmani](http://addyosmani.com/blog/) is a great writer of Javascript design best practices with several free e-books and has countless blog posts on subjects like namespacing.

He used to be a JS engineer for AOL but has recently announced he's moving to Google.

Here's a link specifically to the Namespacing chapter in one of his books, but I suggest you check out his main page as well.

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#detailnamespacing

Comment: Thank you for these information. When I typed 'Javascript namespacing' in google, the first item in the result is always the link that you foward. This is my reference I still want the advice of other about the subjet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `extend()`, because the `NameSpace` object already exists, then use deep extend to the fullest:

```
$.extend( true, NameSpace, {
    subNameSpace : {
        data : {}
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the question you have of proper how to name your object is entirely dependent upon the project. Is the data something other developers shouldn't touch? If not, then one convention is to use an underscore at the beginning of the name. How many `subNameSpace`'s will you have, and will `data` be dependent on one or all of them.

If you're going to namespace off the `jQuery` object then you need to determine whether the method will operate on its own or on a set of selected objects. If the former then just extend `jQuery`, and if the latter then extend `jQuery.fn`.